how to call stored procedure mysql
i'm new to mysql and any help will be good
I created the following stored procedure
and when I call the procedure i'm getting an error message
the sp initializing parameters input and 1 output
and insert data to table according to the event type
and it checks if the value I want to insert is allowed and doesn't create duplicates in the
table and if it's okay it inserts the data else it sends an err msg with the output parameters
CREATE PROCEDURE `employees`.`update_clock`(
    IN i_emp_no INT,
    IN i_event_type INT,
    IN i_event_time DATETIME,
    IN i_start_time DATETIME,
    IN i_end_time DATETIME,
    OUT o_err_msg VARCHAR(200)
)
BEGIN
    DECLARE current_time_a DATETIME;

    -- Initialize current_time_a based on input or current time
    SET current_time_a = IFNULL(i_event_time, NOW());

    IF i_event_type = 0 THEN -- Entry
        IF EXISTS (
            SELECT 1 FROM time_attendance
            WHERE emp_no = i_emp_no
            AND DATE(start_date) = DATE(i_start_time)
            AND (DATE(i_start_time) = DATE(start_date) OR i_start_time < end_date OR i_end_time = end_date)
        ) THEN
            SET o_err_msg = 'Entry already exists for the same day or overlaps with existing time.';
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO time_attendance (emp_no, start_date, end_date)
            VALUES (i_emp_no, i_start_time, NULL);
        END IF;
    ELSEIF i_event_type = 1 THEN -- Exit
        UPDATE time_attendance
        SET end_date = current_time_a
        WHERE emp_no = i_emp_no AND DATE(start_date) = DATE(current_time_a) AND end_date IS NULL;
    ELSEIF i_event_type = 2 THEN -- Manual
        IF i_start_time IS NOT NULL AND i_end_time IS NOT NULL AND DATE(i_start_time) = DATE(i_end_time) THEN
            INSERT INTO time_attendance (emp_no, start_date, end_date)
            VALUES (i_emp_no, i_start_time, i_end_time);
        ELSE
            SET o_err_msg = 'Manual entry requires both start and end times on the same day.';
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;

first, i insert data directly:
insert into time_attendance (emp_no,start_date,end_date) values(10001,'2024-08-13 08:30:00','2024-08-13 09:30:00')

and this is the testing:
SET @error_message = '';
CALL update_clock(10001, 0, null, '2024-08-13 08:30:00', null, @error_message);
SELECT @error_message;


when I call the procedure i'm getting an error message Provide complete and unchanged error message text.

Please publish the error message in full. I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/sNPhdUgL

this is the error message i get when i call the sp - SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL update_clock(10001, 0, null, '2024-08-13 08:30:00', null, @error_message);
' at line 2

I'm using mysql that is use in dbeaver that insatalled on ubuntu 22.4 inside virtual box maybe it doesn't supportted  ?

dbeaver community or dbeaver pro?

community released Jul 8 2024

I haven't used dbeaver, but I suspect you can't execute multiple statements in one call.

If you're using dbeaver, why is this tagged mysql-workbench?

SQLyog has a community version.  It allows executing multiple statements.   I believe what you are doing requires the three statements in another stored procedure.  Variable declarations probably can't be used outside stored procedures.  Just my guess based on the old memory.
